# Any Difference Between 手慣らし and 運動？

Tags: word-choice, usage

If I wanted to say that I've been working out as of late, I'd probably write something like (feel free to correct or suggest):

> 私はこのごろ手慣らしをしている。

Would it be any different if I ｗrote

> 私はこのごろ運動をしている?

I've been told the former sort of translates to 'practice/training' as opposed to 'exercise' though I'm not sure if it matters...?

Any suggestions/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean recently by "as of late" (that's not very common as a phrase in contemporary English)?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use 運動 for this purpose. 手慣らし is incorrect in this context.

手慣らし is made of 手 ("hand") and 慣らし ("accustomization; familiarization"). For example, 手慣らし is what a professional guitarist who has just bought a new guitar will do until he gets comfortable with the new guitar. It's a kind of "training", but it does not refer to acquiring a totally new skill.

Answer (score 1):

> 私はこのごろ手慣らしをしている。

If you want to say like *I've been working out as of late* it does not make sense at all.
It sounds like doing the calisthenics of the fingers or learning handicrafts.

Answer (score 1):

手慣らし is usually used in the sense of "to get used to something."
e.g. (買ったばかりの新車を)手慣らしに運転してみる
Translating the word as "to practice or training" is a bit off.